# What is the probability that they form a match?

Tags: probability

On a dating site, users can select $5$ out of $24$ adjectives to describe themselves. A match is declared between two users if they match on at least $4$ adjectives. If Alice and Bob randomly pick adjectives, what is the probability that they form a match?

My Attempt

Probability space is $24\choose 5$$^2$ we have match for $4$ or $5$ so
for $5$ it's just $24\choose 5$ and for for it's $24\choose 4$ so the overall probability is
$$\frac{^{24}C_5+^{24}C_4}{(^{24}C_5)^2}$$

the given answer is $$\frac{^{24}C_5.(1+5(24-5))}{^{24}C_5.^{24}C_5}$$

Comment: Hint:  Alice's choices are arbitrary,  the problem will be identical for every use case.  So you can reduce your probability space to what are the chances that out of bob's 5 picks,  at least 4 of them are Alices?

Comment: Not posting this analysis as an answer, because comprehensive answers already given.  For what it's worth, per the comment of @Alan, I would have assumed that there is a set $S = \{1,2,\cdots,25\}$ and that *without loss of generality* Alice has selected the subset $\{1,2,3,4,5\}$.  The rest of the analysis generally follows the already given answers.

Comment: Correction: should be $S = \{1,2,\cdots,24\}.$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Going by your method, we count all cases where i) exactly $4$ adjectives match and ii) all $5$ adjectives match.

You are right that number of ways for $5$ match is ${24 \choose 5}$.

Now number of ways for exactly $4$ adjective match -

${24 \choose 4} \cdot 20 \cdot 19$

We first choose $4$ adjectives that are match and then there are $20 \cdot 19$ ways for both of them to choose an adjective each from remaining $20$ adjectives. *You missed the last part.*

So desired probability is,

$\displaystyle \cfrac{{24 \choose 5} + {24 \choose 4} \cdot 20 \cdot 19} {{24 \choose 5} \cdot {24 \choose 5}}$

which is same as the given answer.

Comment: +1 Nice answer!

Comment: @RobertZ thank you. I missed your comment earlier.

Answer (score 1):

For case 4, we can see this.
Alice chooses 5 adjectives, then there are $24 \choose 5$ posibilities.

Then Bob can choose $5 \choose 4$ = $5$  ways for 4 adjective which are same as Alice. The last adjective Bob can choose has $24-5 \choose 1$ = $24-5$ posibilities because last adjective is not in 5 adjectives Alice chosen.

Thus, Bos has $24\choose 5$*5*(24-5) way to choose adjectives which has 4 same adjectives with Alice.

So the answer is same as given.